# How to fetch data from DB Using MONTH("2020-02-25") in Php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**This Is My Code**

```
  $result_sales = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM sales_invoice a LEFT JOIN customer b ON b.cus_tkn=a.cus_tkn WHERE MONTH(a.sales_invodate) = '$month_no'  AND a.invoice_year = '$year'   GROUP  BY a.sbill_no ");
    $result_sales ->execute();
    } else {
    $result_sales = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM sales_invoice a LEFT JOIN sales_invoice_prdct_detail b ON b.sales_invono=a.sales_invono  WHERE MONTH(a.sales_invodate) = '$month_no' AND a.invoice_year= '$year'   ");
    $result_sales ->execute();}
    for ($i=0; $rows_sales  = $result_sales ->fetch(); $i++){
    $order_no = $rows_sales['order_no'];
   echo  $norm_date = $rows_sales['sales_invodate'];
```

No output shows in this whats wrong in this?

Comment: Where did you `echo` result? Post all code please and what variable containe

Comment: Most likely the query returns an error. you cannot use GROUP by like this.

Comment: On a side note, your PDO code is a [cargo cult prepared statement](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/cargo_cult_prepared_statement). You must replace all variables with placeholders

Comment: there is no query error shows in source

Comment: Here im using a select options contains values 1 , 2 , 3 etc and using GET method to check in the database

Comment: MONTHNAME() Fuction also not working

Answer (score -2):

Try this.

```
$result_sales = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM sales_invoice a LEFT JOIN customer b ON b.cus_tkn=a.cus_tkn WHERE MONTH(a.sales_invodate) = $month_no AND a.invoice_year = $year  GROUP BY a.sbill_no");
$result_sales ->execute();
```

Return value from Month() is not a string.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the return value from Month()

Comment: its again shows 0 result!